# How to get image coordinate and corresponding location coordinate of a geo-referenced image in android

Tags: java, android, geospatial

In my android app, I have a geo-referenced image which I am going to use as map. So I need to divide it into tiles. For that I want its top left and bottom right image coordinate(x,y) with location coordinate of corresponding image coordinates using java codes which is supported in android. Can anyone help me with the solution.

**Update:**
I got image coordinates of top left and bottom right corners but still I am not getting location coordinate (lat/long) of top left and bottom right corner. lat/long are already embedded in the image as it is already geo-referenced can anyone tell me how to fetch lat/long of the corners from image.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

For calculating position of image add this to your activity oncreate and for location coordinates checkout below the exif interface code:

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    pubic void onGlobalLayout() {
        int height = imageView.getHeight();
        int width = imageView.getWidth();
        int x = imageView.getLeft();
        int y = imageView.getTop();

        //don't forget to remove the listener to prevent being called again by future layout events:
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

You can embed EXIF data / set it when taking the picture before sending it to a remote server for processing. When posting / sending the data to a remote system, you could send the location data seperate, or leave it as attributes as part of the EXIF data.

Write/Geotag JPEGs (**EXIF** data) in Android

From reading the above, my assumption would be that the following would work:

```
 ExifInterface exif;
 exif = new ExifInterface("/sdcard/DCIM/"+filename+".jpeg");
 double exifLatitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
 double exifLongitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
```

Comment: The image will be used for map so I need its top left and bottom right image coordinate(x,y) as well as location coordinate corresponding to the image coordinate

Comment: The image I am having is not having exif file associated with it though it has an aux.xml file and the image can be in tiff format for other cases. So your solution is giving me top left image coordinate and height and width so from that I can calculate bottom left image coordinate from that but lat/long value associated with these two points cannot be calculated.